# IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, data-science

I have recently started working with tensorflow and this is like my second piece of code and I am stuck while designing this neural network. I am not able to increment the batch size and this problem has been persisting for quite a while.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import math

#importing the data and preprocessing it

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Geeks_Sid\\Documents\\Deep-Learning-A-Z\Deep Learning A-Z\\Volume 1 - Supervised Deep Learning\\Part 1 - Artificial Neural Networks (ANN)\\Section 4 - Building an ANN\\Artificial_Neural_Networks\\Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

#creating a train test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


# Creating layers for Neural network

n_nodes_hl1 = 1000
n_nodes_hl2 = 1000
n_nodes_hl3 = 1000
n_classes = 1
batch_size = 50
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 11])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([11, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])),}


    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']
    print("I was in neural netowrk m")
    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    # OLD VERSION:
    #cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    # NEW:
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        # OLD:
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            current = 0
            for _ in range(80):
                currentprev = current
                current += 100
                epoch_x, epoch_y = tuple(X_train[:,currentprev:current]) ,tuple(y_train[:,currentprev:current])
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:X_test, y:y_test}))

        #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        # NEW:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))



train_neural_network(x)
```

I am dealing with the error that looks like this.

```
    train_neural_network(x)
I was in neural netowrk m
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-7c7cbdae9b34>", line 1, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)

  File "<ipython-input-7-b7e263fe7976>", line 20, in train_neural_network
    epoch_x, epoch_y = tuple(X_train[:,currentprev:current]) ,tuple(y_train[:,currentprev:current])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I am trying a replicate a code of tensorflow MNIST dataset classification where they used this following piece of code. I hope you're able to compare this code with mine. If there are any corrections, please do help me

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    # OLD VERSION:
    #cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    # NEW:
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        # OLD:
        #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        # NEW:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

As you can see, my code is quite similar to the one for MNIST but i am not able to return a particular tuple which is at this piece of code.

```
epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
```

A thanks in advance. if you feel the question is repetitive, i want to explain that i couldn't find others relevant.

Comment: "this is my second piece of code, and i am stuck making a neural network" jesus mate...

Comment: I would `print` the Tensor you're trying to index to get its static shape information. Based on the error it sounds like either a scalar or a vector.

Comment: I tried it, but its of no use. epoch_x and epoch_y are expecting something else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand very well the reshaping you're performing on your data, nor the original format of it but here `y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values` it seems that `y` is a 1D-array while here `tuple(y_train[:,currentprev:current]` you are accessing it like a 2D matrix and the error is telling you that you are using too many (2) indices to index a 1D array.